# C++ Printing array to any output object (by function)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a function, which can 'print' content of array to any output object. It's looking a little bit like this:

```
template <class T, class Z>
void print(T* array, int& size, Z& obj)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
        Z<< array[k] << " ";
    Z<< std::endl;
}
```

I want `obj` to be any output object like `std::cout` or any of `fstream`, so I could call it using:

```
print(arr_name, arr_size, std::cout)
```

or

```
std::ostream file;
print(arr_name, arr_size, file)
```

Unfortunately, in my current verion it doesn't work at all (errors involve '<<' operator). What's wrong? Is it even possible to create such function?

Comment: You basically want `template <class Iter> void print(Iter begin, Iter end, std::ostream& os) { std::for_each(begin, end, [&](decltype(*begin) const& element) { os << element << "\n"; }); }`. And use it with an array like this: `int x[10]; print(begin(x), end(x), std::cout);`

Comment: Note: `int& size` is nonsense (make it `int size)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the name of the argument but the type.

```
Z << array[k] << " ";
```

should be

```
obj << array[k] << " ";
```

In addition, passing the size as non-`const` reference doesn't make much sense as you'll need an l-value, `const int& size` would be better.

But this won't be so much generic in any case. The best solution would be to use iterators and skip plain C arrays totally, and use `std::array` as a replacement (which makes sense since you are working in C++):

```
template <class T, class Z>
void print(const T& data, Z& obj)
{
  for (const typename T::value_type& element : data)
    obj << element;
  obj << std::endl;
}

std::array<int, 5> data = {1,2,3,4,5};
std::vector<std::string> data2;
print(data, std::cout);
print(data2, std::cout);
```

Comment: Oh my god, I was sitting and trying to figure out what was wrong for more that an hour, what a foolish mistake. I would downvote my question if i could. 
ANYWAY, I fixed these things, but I still cannot use it with `print(arr_name, arr_size, std::cout)`

Comment: @mdjdrn1: you should provide a minimal non working example.

Comment: My bad, I'm looking look now at your example, using it in simple program and everything is alright. Thanks a lot!